# Maximize $x^2y$ where $x^2+y^2=100$. (Looking for other approaches)

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, optimization

> For positive numbers $x,y$ we have $x^2+y^2=100$. For which ratio of $x$ to $y$, the value of $x^2y$ will be maximum?
>
> $1)\ 2\qquad\qquad2)\ \sqrt3\qquad\qquad3)\ \frac32\qquad\qquad4)\ \sqrt2$

It is a problem from a timed exam so I'm looking for alternative approaches to solve this problem quickly. Here is my approach:

We have $x^2=100-y^2$, so $x^2y=y(100-y^2)$. By differentiating with respect to $y$ and putting it equal to zero, we have:

$$(100-y^2)-2y^2=0\qquad\qquad y^2=\frac{100}3$$
Hence $x^2=\frac{200}3$ and $\frac{x^2}{y^2}=2$ therefore $\frac{x}{y}=\sqrt2$.

Is there another quick approach to solve it? (like AM-GM inequality or others)

Comment: how about $$\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^2}{2}+y^2\ge 3{(x^2y)}^{2/3}2^{-2/3}$$ when does equality occur

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore that's very nice! it occurs when $\frac{x^2}2=y^2$. You can write it as an answer so that I accept it.

Comment: Answer comes quite quickly out of Lagrange's equations. Turns out we quickly get $x$ and $y$ in terms of the multiplier coefficient $\lambda$ so when we take $x/y$, we immediately get $\pm \sqrt{2}$. The constraint equation tells us it will be $+\sqrt{2}$ but it was made unnecessary due to the multiple choice.

Comment: If you let $u = x/10$ and $v = y/10$ then you are maximizing $1000u^2v$ subject to $u^2 + v^2 = 1$, which is the same as maximizing $u^2v$ along a unit circle so there is no reason for all the $100$ trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Without calculus:**

Let $r:=\left(\dfrac xy\right)^2$. We maximize $ry^3$ under $(r+1)y^2=100$, i.e. we maximize

$$r\left(\frac{100}{r+1}\right)^{3/2}$$ or simply

$$\frac{r^2}{(r+1)^3}.$$

The options give

$$\frac{16}{125},\frac9{64},\frac{324}{2197},\frac4{27}.$$

The largest value is the fourth, corresponding to $\sqrt2$.

Comment: Did you use calculus in your answer?  Honestly, I could not understand what was happening ..

Comment: @lonestudent: of course not, that is the goal of my answer.

Comment: Thanks for comment. Can I ask, how do you get $\frac{324}{2197}$

Comment: @lonestudent: from the ratio $\frac32$, like the others.

Comment: Please let me ask again..How do you get $$\frac{16}{125},\frac9{64},\frac{324}{2197},\frac4{27}.$$
Where do these numbers come from?  I really can't see anything ... Can you give me a little hint?  Your answer seems simple but I really can't see what's going on .. by the way (+1)

Comment: @lonestudent: they come from the problem statement. Read it again.

Comment: I understand now.  You have reached the answer based on the options.  I've been thinking for half an hour..  Where do these numbers come from… $\ddot\smile$ Well.  I got it. If we didn't have options, our work could get harder..

Comment: @lonestudent: you are right, that was said in my second sentence. And by the way, evaluating the function for these four values is costly. It is in fact easier to directly find the local maximum, which does occur at $r=\sqrt2$. But my approach goes to the point, which is to find the optimal ratio.

Answer (score 2):

One approach could be to parameterize the curve $x^2+y^2=100$. Define the functions $x$ and $y$ by $x(t)=10\cos(t)$ and $y(t)=10\sin(t)$ on the interval $(0,\pi/2)$ (this constraint ensures that $x$ and $y$ are bijective and strictly positive, since $\cos(t)>0$ and $\sin(t)>0$ for all $t\in(0,\pi/2)$). The quantity $x^2y$ is then simply $\cos^2(t)\sin(t)$, and we can find its maximum by finding the maximum of $\cos^2(t)\sin(t)$ on $(0,\pi/2)$.

Differentiating and equating the resulting expression to $0$ gives

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left[\cos^2(t)\sin(t)\right]=-2\cos(t)\sin^2(t)+\cos^3(t)=0$$
$$\iff \cos^3(t)=2\cos(t)\sin^2(t)$$
$$\iff \frac{1}{2}=\tan^2(t)$$
$$\iff t=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\text{, since tan(t) is bijective on }(0,\pi/2)$$

Once you've proven that the critical point $t=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$ does indeed correspond to a maximum for $\cos^2(t)\sin(t)$, it follows that the ratio $\frac{x}{y}$ that maximizes $x^2 y$ is

\begin{align*}
\frac{\cos\left(\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}{\sin\left(\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)} &= \frac{1}{\tan\left(\tan^{-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}\\
&= \frac{1}{1/\sqrt{2}}\\
&= \sqrt{2}
\end{align*}

Comment: There is a typo in first line $x^2+y^2=100$

Comment: @Amirali yep, that's a typo. Thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, by *AM-GM inequality*, $x^2y = 2\sqrt{\dfrac{x^2}{2}\cdot \dfrac{x^2}{2}\cdot y^2}\le 2\sqrt{\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{x^2}{2}+\dfrac{x^2}{2}+ y^2\right)^3}{27}}= 2\cdot \sqrt{\dfrac{100^3}{27}}= \dfrac{2,000}{3\sqrt{3}}=\dfrac{2,000\sqrt{3}}{9}\implies (x^2y)_{\text{max}} = \dfrac{2,000\sqrt{3}}{9}$ at $\dfrac{x^2}{2} = y^2\implies x^2=2y^2\implies 3y^2=100\implies y = \dfrac{10\sqrt{3}}{3}, x = y\sqrt{2}=\dfrac{10\sqrt{6}}{3}\implies \boxed{\dfrac{x}{y} = {\sqrt{2}}}$.

**Note:** I just saw the comment by @Albus above **after** posting this answer. Any way, just leave it here....

Comment: Answers are better as answers, not comments, so I think even if you had noticed the comment it would be fine to convert it into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think your solution is fine, the only change I would make it to point out that the constraint $x^2 + y^2 = 100$ can be changed to $x^2 + y^2 = z$ for any positive $z$ without changing the solution, since it is just ratios.  But here is an alternative:

$$x^2 + y^2 = 1$$
$$r = x^2y$$
$$x = wy$$
Write r in terms of w:

$$r = (wy)^2y = w^2y^3$$
$$(wy)^2 + y^2 = 1 \implies y^2 = (1+w^2)^{-1}$$
Using the old "the critical points of $r$ are included in the critical points of $r^2$" trick:
$$r^2 = \dfrac{w^4}{(1 + w^2)^{3}} = \dfrac{1}{w^2 + 3 + 3w^{-2} + w^{-4}} > 0$$

$$d(r^2) = -r^{2}(2w - 6w^{-3} - 4w^{-5}) = 0$$

$$w^6 - 3w^{2} - 2 = 0$$
$$(w^2 - 2)(w^2+1)^2 = 0$$
$$w = \sqrt 2$$