# Maximizing $x^2y$ given $x^2+y^2=100$, without using the AM-GM inequality and calculus tools

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization, proof-writing, solution-verification, maxima-minima

**Problem says:**

> Let $x^2+y^2=100$, where $x,y>0$. For which ratio of $x$ to $y$, the value of $x^2y$ will be maximum?

I know these possible tools:

- AM-GM inequality
- Calculus tools

---

Here, I want to escape from all of the tools I mentioned above.

I will try to explain my attempts in the simplest sentences. (my english is not enough, unfortunately). I will not prove any strong theorem and also I'm not sure what I'm doing exactly matches the math, rigorously.

---

Solution I made:

First, it is not necessary to make these substitutions.  I'm just doing this to work with smaller numbers.

Let, $x=10m, ~y=10n$,

where $0<m<1,~ 0<n<1$, then we have

$$ x^2+y^2=100 \iff m^2+n^2=1$$

$$x^2y=1000m^2n$$

This means,

$$\max\left\{x^2y\right\}=10^3\max\left\{m^2n\right\}$$

$$m^2n=n(1-n^2)=n-n^3$$

Then suppose that,

$$\begin{align}\max\left\{n-n^3 \mid 0<n<1\right\}&=a, a>0&\end{align}$$

This implies

$$n-n^3-a≤0,~ \forall n\in\mathbb (0,1)$$

$$n^3-n+a≥0,~\forall n\in\mathbb (0,1)$$

Then, we observe that

$$\begin{align}n^3-n+a≥0, \forall n\in (0,1) ~ \text{and} ~ \forall n≥1\end{align}$$

This follows

$$ n^3-n+a≥0, ~ \forall n>0.$$

---

Using the last conclusion, I assume  that there exist $u,v>0$, such that

> $$n^3-n+a=(n-u)^2(n+v)≥0.$$
>
> If $n>0$, then the equality occurs, if and only if
>
> $$n=u>0$$

---

Based on these, we have:

$$\begin{align}n^3-n+a= (n-u)^2(n+v)≥0 \end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}n^3-n+a = & n^3 - n^2(2u-v)+ n(u^2 - 2 u v ) + u^2v & \end{align}$$

$$\begin{align} \begin{cases} 2u-v=0 \\ u^2-2uv=-1 \\u^2v=a \\u,v>0 \end{cases} &\implies \begin{cases} v=2u \\ u^2-4u^2=-1 \\ 2u^3=a \\ u,v>0 \end{cases}\\
&\implies \begin{cases}  u=\frac{\sqrt 3}{3} \\ v=\frac{2\sqrt 3}{3}\\ a=2\left(\frac{\sqrt 3}{3} \right)^3=\frac{2\sqrt 3}{9} \end{cases} \end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}n^3-n+\frac{2\sqrt 3}{9} &=\left(n-\frac{\sqrt 3}{3} \right)^2\left(n+\frac{2\sqrt 3}{3}\right)≥0.&\end{align}$$

As a result, we deduce that

$$\begin{align}n-n^3-\frac{2\sqrt 3}{9} &=-\left(n-\frac{\sqrt 3}{3} \right)^2\left(n+\frac{2\sqrt 3}{3}\right)≤0, &\forall n\in (0,1).&\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}\max\left\{n-n^3 \mid 0<n<1\right\}&=\frac{2\sqrt 3}{9}, ~ \text{at }~ n=\frac{\sqrt 3}{3}&\end{align}$$

Finally, we obtain

$$m=\sqrt{1-n^2}=\sqrt{1-\frac 13}=\frac{\sqrt 6}{3}$$

$$\frac xy=\frac mn=\sqrt 2.$$

---

#### Question:

- How much of the things I've done here are correct?

Comment: Relevant https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4119234/460967

Comment: "Using the last conclusion, I will use the my following assumption/lemma (I'm making up a little):"  I'd say you can't make that conclusion without the basis of calculus and principals of continuity.  I mean, that is essentially the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: @fleablood Thanks for comment. Can you elaborate, which part of solution is problematic?

Comment: So you want to maximise $x^2 y = 100y - y^3=f(y)$?

Comment: @rtybase Almost yes...But I need SV.

Comment: So, why not using the "standard approach" of finding $f'(y)=0$?

Comment: @rtybase I was testing the power of algebra. I was testing algebraic tools ..

Comment: You're essentially trying to maximize a cubic without using calculus.  https://www.themathdoctors.org/max-and-min-of-a-cubic-without-calculus/ shows how.

Comment: "Can you elaborate, which part of solution is problematic? "  Well, nothing.  But you said you didn't want to use calculus.  In my opinion your lemma is essentially calculus.  (But I don't see why avoiding calculus is that important.)

Comment: @MichaelLugo Thank you for reference.

Comment: I think Michael Lugo's comment should be made into an answer.

Comment: $x= 10cosa, y = 10sina$

$100cos^2(a)sin(a) = 100(1-sin^2(a))sin(a)$; Let sin(a) = t

$\implies 100(t-t^3)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is good and the easiest way without calculus.

---

**An Approach that Exposes the Core Ideas**

The following approach is a slight modification of yours that simplifies the algebra using [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas).

If
$$
x^2+y^2=100\tag1
$$
then
$$
\begin{align}
x^2y
&=100\cos^2(\theta)\cdot10\sin(\theta)\tag{2a}\\
&=1000\left(\sin(\theta)-\sin^3(\theta)\right)\tag{2b}
\end{align}
$$
So we wish to maximize $\sin(\theta)-\sin^3(\theta)$ for $0\lt\theta\lt\frac\pi2$ (since $x,y\gt0$). Suppose the maximum is $m$. Then your assumption/lemma says that $s-s^3-m=0$ has a double root. That is,
$$
s^3-s+m=(s-r)^2(s-q)\tag3
$$
Vieta's formulas say that for a monic cubic polynomial,
$$
\begin{align}
r+r+q&=0\tag{4a}\\
r^2+rq+rq&=-1\tag{4b}\\
r^2q&=-m\tag{4c}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(4a)}$: the sum of the roots is the negative of the coefficient of $s^2$
$\text{(4b)}$: the sum of the pairwise products of the roots is the coefficient of $s$
$\text{(4c)}$: the product of the roots is the negative of the constant coefficient

Now things just fall into place:
$\text{(4a)}$ says that $q=-2r$
$\text{(4b)}$ says that $-3r^2=-1$, that is $r=\frac1{\sqrt3}$
$\text{(4c)}$ says that $-2r^3=-m$, that is $m=\frac2{3\sqrt3}$

Thus, the maximum of $s-s^3$ is $\frac2{3\sqrt3}$ which happens at $s=\frac1{\sqrt3}$, which is a value that $\sin(\theta)$ attains for $0\lt\theta\lt\frac\pi2$.

Thus, the maximum of $x^2y=1000\cdot\frac2{3\sqrt3}=\frac{2000}{3\sqrt3}$.

Comment: Yes, I know I made up the "lemma." It's actually, not a "lemma".  Something I made up. It has no mathematical rigor.  I was just trying to write what was going on in my head. Thank you for your answer.!

Comment: I'm actually curious about the true mathematical version of the lemma I made up. Maybe you want to leave a comment..

Comment: The part that bothered me a little was that the way to show that "lemma" would usually be to use calculus. However, looking at plot of the function, it does not seem unreasonable to assume your lemma. It's one of those "assume it because you can see it, until you can prove it" things.

Comment: Did you mean, I can start: suppose that there exist $ u, v >0$ such that .... Yes, actually my request from you was this...  What is the true mathematical version of "lemma"?  For, although this is based on calculus, it does not involve rigorous mathematical representations. I think you know my goal.. Proving that there exist $u,v>0$.

Comment: One can state that for a polynomial $p$, if $p(x_0)=0$ and $p(x)\le0$ for $x$ in an open interval around $x_0$, then $p(x)=(x-x_0)^{2n}q(x)$ for some integer $n$ and polynomial $q$ where $q(x_0)\lt0$. (There is a similar statement for $p(x)\ge0$ and $q(x_0)\gt0$). However, while these seem very reasonable and believable, I think a rigorous proof requires calculus.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative approach without calculus. Considering that $x^2y = \lambda$ and $x^2+y^2=10^2$ are analytic, at it's maximum, $x^2y$ should be tangent to $x^2+y^2=10^2$ then

$$
\frac{\lambda}{y}+y^2-10^2=0
$$

so, at tangency $y^3-10^2y+\lambda = (y-r_1)^2(y-r_2)$

Equating coefficients we have

$$
\cases{
r_1^2r_2 +\lambda = 0\\
r_1^2+2r_1r_2+10^2=0\\
2r_1+r_2 = 0
}
$$

now solving, we have

$$
\cases{
r_1 = \pm\frac{10}{\sqrt{3}}\\
r_2 = \mp\frac{20}{\sqrt{3}}\\
\lambda = \frac{2000}{3\sqrt{3}}
}
$$

so the maximum is $\frac{2000}{3\sqrt{3}}$ and choosing $y^* = \frac{10}{\sqrt{3}}$ we have $x^* = 10\sqrt{\frac 23}$

Attached a plot showing in red $x^2+y^2=10^2$ and in black the level curves of $x^2y$

[image]

Comment: Thank you.! (+1) But unfortunately I cannot accept your answer.  Because proof verification is required for my attempts.

Comment: No problem. I hope I have been helpful.

Comment: Of course your answer is helpful and deserves more upvotes.!

Comment: I spent a little time last night on a similar method, and got bogged down. Thanks for doing the work !